# submit event not capturing submit type input

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a Ajax GET request as mentioned below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#comment-edit-form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: '/comments/edit/' + $(this).attr('comment_pk') + '/',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){}
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The form is something like this

```
<form method="get" id="comment-edit-form">
..

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="preview" value="Preview">
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

In this form, I have two different submit buttons! each has different operation!

The GET request URL I traced is something like below

```
?input1=1&input2=2...
```

I am expecting `?input1=1&input2=2&submit=`
or `?input1=1&input2=2&preview=`

Why I am not able to observe "submit" or "preview" names in the request??

Comment: why not just write the type as `'GET'` instead of getting the method? It will be shorter and also simplifies errors in the future.

Answer (score 3):

This is because jQuery only [serializes the nodeTypes `input, select, textarea and keygen`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=_rsubmittable) with input types that are not [`submit,button, image, file or reset`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=_rsubmittable).

Looking at the jQuery source code, you can tell that form elements' input type is checked against the following regular expression:

```
 /^(?:submit|button|image|reset|file)$/i
```

This check is in `.serializeArray` which is called by `.serialize` in your code.

---

For the interested reader - this is the [complete filter](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=serializeArray):

```
return this.name &&  // has a name
       !jQuery(this).is(":disabled") &&  // is not a disabled input
       rsubmittable.test(this.nodeName) && // is either input, select,textarea or keygen 
       !rsubmitterTypes.test(type) && // the test explained above
       (this.checked || !manipulation_rcheckableType.test(type)); // checked
```